# How to recall stop drawing from outside of map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Drawing Manager is using [image] to Stop (Not End) the Drawing session. How can I call it from other button from outside of the Map canvas?

For example if I have a button like:

```
<button type="button" id="stopDrawing"</button>
<button type="button" id="startDrawing"</button>
```

I do not want to end all Drawing Manager Session.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the hand the `drawingMode` will be set to `null`, you may do the same :

```
drawingManagerInstance.setDrawingMode(null);
```